# Understanding clip-path

Tags: html, css

Currently I am trying to learn HTML, along with CSS and have come across clip-paths. Namely from this [website](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EVQweM).

My understanding is that using clip-paths, such as the polygon attribute, allows you to prevent certain parts from being rendered thus allowing you to create unique looking background containers or so.

However, when I try to do it on my HTML code, with the CSS being directly copied, I do not see a similar behavior. My behavior is that it simply behaves like a large rectangle. Why is that?

This is the HTML:

```
<header class="myClass">

    <h1>MyHeader</h1>

    <p>COmments
    </p>

    <p>Ever More comments</p>

    <p>Yep, ever more lines of code</p>
</header>
```

Edit: This is the CSS.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300|Arimo);

html {
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;

  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 4%, 100% 93%, 0 100%);

  padding: 5%;
  columns: 3;
}

h1 {
  color: yellow;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: You need to put the CSS in the question.

Comment: Try `-webkit-clip-path`. The unprefixed version seems to only be supported in FF.

Comment: CSS must be posted here, not "that link", which can disappear tomorrow and help no one.

Comment: Make sure you use proper browser, as clip-path is not cross-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consult [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) for information on browser support for this feature, and you will find that some browsers require vendor prefixes; for instance, Chrome requires `-webkit-clip-path`. The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) also provides this information.

You could have detected this via the style inspector. Chrome would have shown the `clip-path` property as "invalid property value". Firefox requires no prefix.

Answer (score -1):

The CSS for clip-path in chrome is supported as "-webkit-clip-path".

Use:

```
-webkit-clip-path:  polygon(0 0, 100% 4%, 100% 93%, 0 100%);
```

The browser will now render the effect.

Comment: Thank you very much, makes sense.